# Unable to run Enable-Migration VS2013 SP4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nuget, entity-framework-migrations

I am using VS2013 Community Edition SP4 to create an MVC 5 website. It uses EntityFramework v6 I am attempting to extend the default AspNetUsers database by adding a secondary table to hold other data, however when I try to run `Enable-Migration` I get this error:

```
Enable-Migration : The term 'Enable-Migration' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-Migration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-Migration:String) [], 
                              CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have attempted the following remedies suggested by Google searching:

- Having the solution open
- Cleaning and rebuilding solution
- Restarting VS2013
- Removing and reinstalling NuGet
- Running the `Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease` command
- Ensuring VS2013 is running as Administrator

Is there something else I can try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct term is `enable-migrations`.

Here's some other useful information copy pasted from an answer I gave to a similar question.

```
add-migration InitialCreate
```

This creates a migration. InitialCreate is actually a string and you can change it to whatever you want. This command will generate the scripts needed to create the database from strach.

```
update-database
```

This command verifies the database and applies the migration (or migrations - there can be multiple) required in order to get the database up-to-date.

This is the initial setup. If you do further changes to your first code first classes, or add more, you will just have to add a new migration and then execute it.

```
add-migration AddedFirstName
update-database
```

It's that simple!

There are some more advanced concepts like seed, rollback, update to specific migration, etc., but what I have typed above covers the basics and the day to day usage of migrations.

I recommend you to read this article which explains everything in much more detail: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Nice answer! Answered the question and provided extra details :)